# CanCan 2.0 create/update authorization

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

From what I understand, CanCan authorizes the create and update actions once at load and again when the params hash is assigned.

Is there a way to skip the second authorization check with the new params hash? Here's a scenario where this causes a problem:

I have model that blocks editing when the date is in the past (basically the records become history once a date passes). If I edit a record whose date is still in the future, and assign it a date in the past, rather than having the validation deal with it, the ability that blocks historical records raises a CanCan::Unauthorized exception. This is bad for usability. Is there a way around this?

Comment: please put here your authorization condition. I think you might be doing the conditional with the to-be saved object instead of the persisted object

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to allow opening only records with date in the future for edit (`edit` action, editing form), but be able to perform `update` action (saving the form) for all records, even with passed date in params.

Probobly, you should write different abilities for `edit` and `update` actions. Like

```
can :edit, YourModel do |model|
  model.date > Date.today # something like this
end

can :update, YourModel
```

But you need to add additional check with this approach (in `update` action, maybe, or in validator), because anybody can change record by sending generated by hands post request.

Comment: That's not good. It would be possible to update any model this way. You just couldn't have a form to do it. But with something like curl you could update it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your current situation but I think you could do something like this.

```
can :update, Model do |model|
  persisted_date = model.changes[:date].first
  persisted_date > Date.today 
end
```

Comment: Remember this is CanCan 2. My abilities rules lock everything down as needed. The problem is when submitting a form and the user inputs a past date (which is blocked by CanCan), the app redirects to an error page rather than showing the form with a validation error. This is a usability issue I'm trying to fix. Submitting the wrong date and getting some error page is bad UX.

Comment: can you show abilities codes you have? I'm not familiar with older versions of cancan

Comment: What do you mean older versions? I'm using CanCan 2. I don't think you understand the question. The abilities work as I need them to. What I would like to skip is the authorization performed on the submitted params hash so as to let my validations do their job.